# jQuery + ASP.NET: jQuery click event doesn't fire

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm having an issue using JQuery within an ASP.NET website. I want to bind a common click handler to multiple similar elements (generated through a ListView for those familiar with ASP.NET). My assumption was to use a class selector as follows (as an example):

```
$('.standard-group').click(function () {
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

This relates back to a series of divs having this class:

```
<div class="standard-group">
    some content
</div>

<div class="standard-group">
    some other content
</div>
```

Furthermore, the content is generated inside a ContentPlaceholder and merged into a master page (2 nested master pages actually). I've tried putting the click handler between `<script></script>` tags inside a second ContentPlaceholder that injects it's content into the `<head>` section of the page, tried putting it with the content in the main ContentPlaceholder all to no avail. What ends up happening is that the generated page loads correctly and I can inspect the source and see the function there, but no event is raised. I suspect it's something to do with the master page/server processing scenario, but can't pinpoint it.

Any help out there?

Comment: Can you show some sample pages (view source from your favorite browser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your script for adding event could be executing before the element being created, you can use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to delegate event to document.

```
$(document).on('click', '.standard-group', function () {
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

**delegated events**

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they
>   must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().
>   To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, perform event
>   binding inside a document ready handler for elements that are in the
>   HTML markup on the page. If new HTML is being injected into the page,
>   select the elements and attach event handlers after the new HTML is
>   placed into the page. Or, use delegated events to attach an event
>   handler, as described next. [Reference](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the answer and the explanation of why. It now works, but only when I put the function inside the MainContentPlaceholder, and not HeadContentPlaceholder. I guess I don't know enough about the ASP.NET page life-cycle and what order stuff gets executed in.

Answer (score 1):

delegate the click event to `document` with `on()`

```
 $(document).on('click','.standard-group',function () {
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

[link](http://jq4you.blogspot.com/2013/02/jquery-direct-and-delegate-on-event.html) to read more about `on()`